# Edit values in nested dictionary from the list (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

sorry if it's been asked, but I could not find the correct answer. I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
list2 = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
```

and a nested dictionary:

```
myDict = {
    1: {'first': None, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    2: {'first': None, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    3: {'first': None, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    5: {'first': None, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    8: {'first': None, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    }
```

How do I insert values in each of dictionaries inside myDict, based on key?
**Expected output:**

```
myDict= {
    1: {'first': 100, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    2: {'first': 200, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    3: {'first': 300, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    5: {'first': 400, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    8: {'first': 500, 'second': None, 'third': None} ,
    }
```

what I tried:

```
for i in list1:
   for j in list2:
       myDict[i]['first'] = j
print(myDict)
```

What I get (it replaces all values with the last item in the list)

```
{1: {'first': 500, 'second': None, 'third': None},
2: {'first': 500, 'second': None, 'third': None},
3: {'first': 500, 'second': None, 'third': None},
5: {'first': 500, 'second': None, 'third': None},
8: {'first': 500, 'second': None, 'third': None}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You are actually doing more like 25 updates instead of 5, with each key getting  updated once per value in list2

Comment: @Chris thanks, I thought something was off

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is zip

```
for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
   myDict[i]['first'] = j
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never used zip before, certanly a useful thing :) Will read some more documentation about it

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
for k,i in zip(list1,list2):
    myDict[k]['first'] = i
```

and the output:

```
{1: {'first': 100, 'second': None, 'third': None},
 2: {'first': 200, 'second': None, 'third': None},
 3: {'first': 300, 'second': None, 'third': None},
 5: {'first': 400, 'second': None, 'third': None},
 8: {'first': 500, 'second': None, 'third': None}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
i = 0 
while i < len(list1):
myDict[list1[i]]["first"] = list2[i]
i += 1
```

Result:

```
{  1: {'first': 100, 'second': None, 'third': None},
   2: {'first': 200, 'second': None, 'third': None},
   3: {'first': 300, 'second': None, 'third': None},
   5: {'first': 400, 'second': None, 'third': None},
   8: {'first': 500, 'second': None, 'third': None}}
```